# Building FFMPEG for Visual Studio development

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013, ffmpeg

I'm trying to use ffmpeg in Visual Studio 2013 C++ software (ultimately as part of an OpenCV project) - but right now I'm just trying to get basic FFMPEG functionality.  In general, when building in Visual Studio, I build 64--bit software with Multi-threaded DLL runtime libraries.  I have built ffmpeg using the general instructions for 'Native Windows compilation using ... MinGW-w64' at http://ffmpeg.org/platform.html#Windows (I provide a more detailed set of steps I followed below...).

After building the ffmpeg software on my system, I tried to create a simple 'hello world' project in Visual Studio 2013.  Specifically, I tried to implement the initial tutorial file presented at http://dranger.com/ffmpeg/tutorial01.html.  Upon building the project, I get the error:

> c:\msys64\usr\local\ffmpeg\libavutil\common.h(45): fatal error C1083: Cannot
>   open include file: 'libavutil/avconfig.h': No such file or directory

The following are the detailed steps I took to build ffmpeg and create my basic Visual Studio project:

============ Building ffmpeg ===============

1. Downloaded and intalled msys2-x86_64-20160205.exe from http://msys2.github.io
2. Ran `update-core` to update the Msys2 install
3. Ran `pacman -Suu` (twice) to complete the update (following the instructions about updating shortcuts, etc.)
4. Then I quit out of the MSys2 shell and opened the MinGW-w64 Win64 Shell.  In this new shell:
5. Installed the following packages using `pacman -S <package-name>`  The list of packages I installed is: make, pkg-config, diffutils, mingw-w64-x86_64-yasm, mingw-w64-x86_64-gcc, mingw-w64-x86_64-SDL, git
6. Then I cd'd into `cd /usr/local`
7. Ran `git clone https://git.ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.git ffmpeg`
8. I wanted to build the ffmpeg library 'out-of-tree' of this MSys64 folder.   So, in the regular file system of my Windows machine I created a folder at C:\ffmpeg
9. Back in the Win64 Shell, I cd'd to this new folder: `cd /c/ffmpeg`
10. Then ran `/usr/loca/ffmpeg/configure --enable-shared`
11. Then `make -r`
12. And, finally `make install`

Now, if I had to guess, my 'flaw' was in the options I used when calling the 'configure' script of ffmpeg.  Do I need to use particular options so that I can take the ffmpeg libraries built here and use them as dynamic (DLL) libraries in Visual Studio?

========== Configuring my Visual Studio Project ============

Here's how I created a simple hello world project in Visual Studio to see if ffmpeg is working.

1. I created a new Visual C++ 'Empty Project' in Visual Studio 2013
2. I then configured the project properties as follows:

   a. In C/C++ => General => Additional Include Directories, I put

   > C:\msys64\usr\local\ffmpeg

   b. In Linker=>General => Additional Library Directories, I pointed to each of the built library folders (basically I pointed at *all* of the libraries that were built to ensure I was not inadvertently missing the critical one).  The list is as follows:

   - C:\ffmpeg\libavcodec
   - C:\ffmpeg\libavdevice
   - C:\ffmpeg\libavfilter
   - C:\ffmpeg\libavformat
   - C:\ffmpeg\libavutil
   - C:\ffmpeg\libswresample
   - C:\ffmpeg\libswscale
   - C:\ffmpeg

   c. In Linker=> Input => Additional Dependencies, I pointed to the particular libraries (again - I pointed to all of the ones present).  The list is:

   - avcodec.lib
   - avdevice.lib
   - avfilter.lib
   - avformat.lib
   - avutil.lib
   - swresample.lib
   - swscale.lib
3. I then created a new source file called 'tut01.c' and copied/pasted the code from http://dranger.com/ffmpeg/tutorial01.c
4. Then hit F7 and got the error specified above about not finding avconfig.h

The above is my best guess as to the steps I need to follow to get this working in Windows (btw, it's Windows 10, 64-bit) & Microsoft Visual Studio 2013.  What should I change to get this basic program to build and run?

Comment: If header not found, the compiler complains sth wrong with include directory. There's nothing to do with linker or external libs at this moment. So go to project property page -> Configuration Properties -> VC++ Directories -> Include Directories, add your headers' dir.

Comment: @halfelf  Thanks for the tip.  The problem is (and I should have mentioned this in my post) the avconfig.h header is not present in my libavutil folder.  This is why I think I have configured the ffmpeg build incorrectly.

Comment: I see, sorry for not reading it carefully. In this case, you can simply find and copy it from ffmpeg source dir to where it should be. However, traditionally speaking, we configure these libs with "--prefix=dir" option, so that all libs and headers will be in the prefix dir after build.

Answer (score 1):

@halfelf, thanks for the responses.  They caused me to take another look at my files and I realize I was pointing at the wrong location for the include (and lib) files.  Turns out that, upon building ffmpeg, it places in lateral folders `/usr/local/include` and `/usr/local/bin`, I guess, a more complete set of include and library files, respectively (including avconfig.h!)  I updated my Visual Studio project properties to point at these folders which solved that problem.

But subsequently, I ran into a new problem of 'PIX_FMT_RGB24' not being identified.  However, I *think* this is related to the tutorial file I'm using being out of date.  I can delete those (and related) lines and the code will build and execute (though it does not do much since the 'money' lines of code are removed).  But at least base features of ffmpeg appear to be working.

Comment: `PIX_FMT_xxx` is old macro names, change to `AV_PIX_FMT_xxx` instead. Check `libavutil/pixfmt.h` for available pixel format macros.

Comment: @halfelf  Thanks!  That was the issue.  Made that one replacement and Tut01 now compiles & runs!!